# Missing library when bootstraping Ubuntu 12.04 with Ruby 1.9.3 from source

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ruby

Apologies for any incorrect terminology.

I'm using Chef to automate server deployment.

I've built an AMI that has Ruby 1.9.3 compiled from source and then chef takes over from that point.

When ruby is compiled from source libruby.so.1.9 gets added to /usr/lib.

The problem is that require 'mysql' fails during the chef run because it's looking for  libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9 which does not exist.

I can fix this by running `sudo apt-get install libruby1.9.1` but I think there's probably a more elegant solution, ideally one that I can add to the AMI or the chef deploy that fixes this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Right Way to do this is to install Ruby from a package instead of from source. Based on the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/r/ruby1.9.1/ruby1.9.1_1.9.3.0-1ubuntu1/changelog) for the `ruby1.9.1` package in Ubuntu 12.04, it's actually version 1.9.3p0 even though the package name implies it is 1.9.1. If you're compiling from source because you need 1.9.3 you should simply use the packages from Ubuntu. If there's another reason you're compiling from source, try to find an Ubuntu package or build the package yourself.